# error when using ng-include in angularjs to access a text file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

folder structure

`project
   -app
     -home
        files.html
   -uploads
     -akp.txt`

I am trying in access abc.txt from files.html

files.html

`<ng-include src="'../uploads/akp.txt'"></ng-include>`

but I get an error as:

[image]

Comment: if you are getting it from `files.html`, then you need to escape 2 parent directories: `app` and `home`. So don't you want `../../` before `uploads`?

Comment: tried that as well, getting the same error code `404`

Comment: akp.txt is different than abc.txt does this file exist aswell ?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo. edited the questions